# jsf.ajax.request not working completely

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am attempt to make a custom autocomplete box but I am having some trouble. Right now I have an input that calls this function on keydown

```
 function pingAutoComplete(event)
 {
    console.log("pingAutoComlete Called");
    window.clearTimeout(window.keyTimeout);


     //Wait 2 seconds before we attempt to pingAutoComplete incase user has not finished typing
      window.keyTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
       jsf.ajax.request(event, "keydown", {execute:'searchTerm',render:'autoCompletePanel'})
       autoCompleteLayoutPanel.show();
       return false;
    }, 2000);
    return false;

 }
```

The auto complete panel contains a bunch of selects that look like this

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="vehicleResult" title="Vehicles"
    value="#{searchBean.searchTerm}"
    converter="entityConverter"
    required="false"
    rendered="#{!searchBean.filterAutoComplete().isEmpty()}">

    <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.filterAutoComplete()}"
        var="searchItem" itemValue="#{searchItem}"
        itemLabel="#{searchItem.displayString}"
        itemLabelEscaped="true" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

Now when the javascript is called it seems to be hitting searchBean.filterAutoComplete() on the back end, but it is not actually updating the select list in the gui. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the exact client ID. That is the value of the `id` attribute of the generated HTML element, not of the JSF component itself. If the JSF components are placed in a `<h:form>`, then the client ID will by default be prepended with its ID.

Thus the following panelgroup

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGroup id="autoCompletePanel">
```

will have a client ID of `form:autoCompletePanel`. You need to specify exactly that ID in the `render` attribute. The same rules also applies to `execute` by the way.

Comment: Right I actually did do that, but I tried to simplify it a little bit for the form. It is actually hitting the back end so the rendered seems to be finding autocompletepanel.

Comment: Try to not oversimplify the code in the future, but to post real working code. Back to your problem, the JSF component with client ID `form:autoCompletePanel` does by itself **not** have the `rendered` attribute, right?

Comment: Sorry I was gone for so long, meeting after meeting after meeting. Anyway I ended up going with a primefaces comp called <p:remotecommand>  to get it working.

Comment: Oh? If you're already using PrimeFaces, why not using its `<p:autoComplete>`?